# Inequality on the moment generating function of a centered random variable which is bounded above

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, moment-generating-function

I am stuck on the first part of problem 8.2 of the book "*A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition*" by Luc Devroye:

> Show that for any $s > 0$, and any random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$, $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma^2, X \leq c$,
> $$ \mathbb{E}(e^{sX}) \leq e^{f(\sigma^2/c^2)}, $$
> where
> $$ f(u) = \log \left( \frac{1}{1+u}e^{-csu} + \frac{u}{1+u}e^{cs} \right). $$

The purpose of the problem is to prove Bennett's inequality. I've searched for how Bennett's is usually proved, and it seems like the usual trick is to expand $\mathbb{E}(e^{sX})$
with the Taylor series, followed by applying an inequality on the terms in $\mathbb{E}(X^k), k \geq 3$. However, this is not what the author has in mind here, and I cannot figure out any way to invoke the term $e^{-csu}$ in any inequality.

Comment: Apply Jensen's Inequality.  If this isn't a sufficiently clear hint, choose units of measurement in which $c=1$ to simplify the expression.  Then, *draw a picture* of the graph of $x\to e^{sx}$ for an arbitrary $s.$  Notice the graph is convex on the interval $[-u,1]$ for any $u\ge 0,$ which means the line segment joining the endpoints of the graph over this interval lies *above* the value of the graph at $0 = E[X].$ (It is strictly above when $s\ne 0.$) Translate this visual observation into arithmetic.

Comment: @whuber I want to generalize the bounds from c=1 and apply a convexity inequality. I know that X is upper bounded by c, but what is our lower bound? I find that the arithmetic checks out if the lower bound is -cu but I can't make sense of why that should be the lower bound.

Comment: There is no loss of generality in taking $c=1.$  Where in your post do you ask about a lower bound?

Comment: @whuber If I understand correctly, your hint seems not sharp enough -- it only proves $e^{f(\sigma^2)} \geq 1$, but the goal is $e^{f(\sigma^2)} \geq E[e^{sX}]$ for $s > 0$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Where do you obtain only $1$ for the LHS?  You seem to be focusing on the exceptional case $s=1.$

Comment: @whuber  Can you kindly post a more complete answer to elaborate? After a long attempt, I believe this inequality is much more involved than a simple application of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @whuber Seconded. I would highly appreciate some elaboration as I am having a hard time following why this reasoning proves the inequality.

Comment: I have awarded a bounty for the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345543/inequality-on-the-moment-generating-function-of-a-centered-random-variable-which/4659226?noredirect=1#4659226) in math stack exchange, and received a great answer.  Those who are still interested can refer to that link.